# Cannot scroll dropdown list of AutoCompleteTextView on Android

Tags: android, scroll, android-softkeyboard, autocompletetextview

I have an `AutoCompleteTextView`on an `AlertDialog`. The dropdown list with the suggestions gets partly covert by the keyboard (see screenshot). The result is that I cannot scroll the list.

[image]

I already managed to move the dialog to the top of the screen to get more space. When I set `android:dropDownHeight` to a small value like 150dp the dropdown list is not covert by the keyboard anymore and scrolling works just fine but setting `dropDownHeight` to a fix value doesn't seem to be a good solution. I want to avoid using "magic numbers" because otherwise I have no guarantee that it will work on all screens.

How can I solve this?

Comment: how do you know it is covered by a keyboard?

Comment: @pskink You can see it on the screenshot. As I mentioned I did set `dropDownHeight` to a smaller value so that the complete dropdown list became visible. There is no other view that could cover it.

Comment: so "Birnen" is not the last item?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I finally got it working. This line of code did it for me. This way the dropdown list is always fitting with the keyboard.

```
alertDialog.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE);
```

Comment: SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE is deprecated

Comment: It is not working for me

Answer (score 0):

That is because the window of your app is not being resized properly. Try to add in your manifest for this activity `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"`

Comment: hummm maybe alert dialog has more styles than you need for this. Have you tried this on a DialogFragment?

Comment: No, not yet. I will give it a try and let you know.

Comment: Tried using a DialogFragment, but this didn't work either.